# url.action passing parameter values from angular object

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4

How can i pass the Url.action with parameter from angular object?
refer to `new { id ="{{item.Title}}", title = "" }` section in code below.
i cant do it like `id ={{item.Title}}` this renders it as an string.

```
 <div ng-app class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div ng-controller="MostViewedToolController" class="span2">
                <ul class="nav nav-list">
                    <li><a href="#"><h4><b>Most Viewed</b></h4></a></li>
                    <li ng-repeat="item in tools">
                        <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "home", new { id ="{{item.Title}}", title = "" })"> {{item.Title}}</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            @RenderBody()
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: You have to store Url in angular controller. So you can utilize that parameter over here.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42695763/706363 - I have created an URL HtmlHelper extension to help bind angular and MVC routes.

Answer (score 2):

Please follow the below process, i have implemented it and it's working fine.

< a  ng-href="@Url.Action("Index","home")?id={{item.ID}}&title={{item.Title}}"> link_name < / a>

Answer (score 0):

This fixed it.

```
<a ng-href="@Url.Action("Index", "home"){{item.ID}}/{{item.Title}}"> {{item.Title}}</a>
```

Comment: it will not work if you bind thin on parameted view. it will add your value to next url value.