# How to pass id from angular view to asp.net mvc controller?

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to add angularjs in an already build project. I am using angularjs for the index page. I need to call the mvc controller for edit and delete instead of angularjs controller and i need to pass id to the mvc controller.
I have used the code.

```
 <a href="@Url.Action("EditNewsLetter","NewsLetter")/?id = {{item.Id }}">Edit</a> |
 <a href="@Url.Action("DeleteNewsLetter","NewsLetter")/?id = {{item.Id }}">Delete</a>
```

but it is not passing the values to the controller when i am clicking.

It shows error id cannot be null.I don't have much experience in angular.
So please help me to get out of this problem.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25182830/html-actionlink-and-angularjs-value

Comment: `item` is MVC viewModel property OR angular variable ?

Comment: @PankajParkar Angular property

Comment: @simba then it looks good for me, I think just remove whitespace & make it `<a href="@Url.Action("EditNewsLetter","NewsLetter")/?id={{item.Id }}">` should restrict `encoding` of whitespace while hitting URL to server

Comment: @KartikeyaKhosla Thank you that link helped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked.

```
<a data-ng-href="@Url.Action("EditNewsLetter","NewsLetter")/{{item.Id}}" target="_self">Edit </a> <a data-ng-href="@Url.Action("DeleteNewsLetter","NewsLetter")/{{item.Id}}" target="_self">Delete </a>
```