# How to pass angularjs value in @Html.ActionLink link route value?

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a role based @html.ActionLink() .Which show or hide link based on user permission.ASP.NET MVC5 Default  @html.ActionLink() works fine.

But i want to pass angularjs value as a route value.

```
  @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", "Branches", new { id = "{{branch.BranchId}}" })
```

but this code render following code

```
<a href="/Branches/Edit?Length=8" id="22">Edit</a>
```

i found this link but can't find a solution. 
[@Html.ActionLink and Angularjs value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25182830/html-actionlink-and-angularjs-value)
I want to pass angularjs value using actionLink() not  Url.Action()

Thanks

Comment: try this  @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", "Branches", new { id = "{{branch.BranchId}}" },null)

Comment: yes already tried this . not working :( .

Comment: this won't work.  the `Html.ActionLink` is rendered server side, while Angularjs is rendered client side.  At the time the `ActionLink` is created, the information from the expression would not be available.

Answer (score 1):

This could work for you. Just remove the controller name from the parameters.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = "{{branch.BranchId}}" })
```

Or like this with controller name

```
@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", "Branches", new { id = "{{branch.BranchId}}" }, null)
```

Or you can try this

```
@{
     var link = Url.Action("Edit", "Branches", new { id = "{{branch.BranchId}}" });
     link = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(link);
 }
 <a href="@link">Edit</a>
```

Comment: sorry not working .both generate this . 
<a href="/Branches/Edit/%7B%7Bbranch.BranchId%7D%7D">Edit</a>

Comment: It seems like there is some issue in binding from AngularJS expression {{branch.BranchId}} here.